# How to return something only after some asynchronous function in map function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I store author's user id of each message, so I wanted to get username of that user . So how can i return list item only after database call in map function? I hope I explained it correctly. Here's the code:

```
const messagesRef = firebase.firestore().collection(`/chatrooms/${props.currentChatRoom}/messages`);
const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });
return (
    <div className={classes.ChatRoomContainer}>
        <ul>
            {messages && messages !== null ? messages && messages.map(msg => {
                const messageClass = msg.userId === props.userId ? classes.Sent : classes.Recieved;
                let messageAuthorUsername;
                firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(msg.author).get().then(doc => {
                    messageAuthorUsername = doc.data().userName;
                    return <li className={messageClass + ' ' + classes.Message} key={msg.id}>
                        <label>{msg.author !== props.userId ? messageAuthorUsername : 'You'}</label>
                        <p className={classes.MessageContent}>{msg.messageContent}</p>
                    </li>
                });
            }) : <p>Loading...</p>}
        </ul>
        <form className={classes.Form} onSubmit={(e) => props.onMessageSentHandler(e)}>
            <input className={classes.Input} placeholder="Type your message..." onChange={(e) => props.onInputChangedHandler(e)} value={props.messageInput} />
            <button className={classes.Btn}><FontAwesomeIcon color="white" icon='paper-plane' className={classes.PaperPlaneIcon} /></button>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

Then I tried code below but it creates a memory leak. What I'm trying to do is to update username of each message by user id.

```
const [updatedMessages, setUpdatedMessages] = React.useState([]);

const messagesRef = firebase.firestore().collection(`/chatrooms/${props.currentChatRoom}/messages`);
const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (messages) {
        for(let message in messages) {
            firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(messages[message].author).get().then(doc => {
                messages[message] = {...messages[message], authorUsername: doc.data().userName};
                setUpdatedMessages(prev => [...prev, messages[message]]);
            });
        }
    }
}, [messages]);

return (
    <div className={classes.ChatRoomContainer}>
        <ul>
            {updatedMessages ? updatedMessages.map(msg => {
                const messageClass = msg.userId === props.userId ? classes.Sent : classes.Recieved;
                return <li className={messageClass + ' ' + classes.Message} key={msg.id}>
                    <label>{msg.author !== props.userId ? msg.authorUsername : 'You'}</label>
                    <p className={classes.MessageContent}>{msg.messageContent}</p>
                </li>
            }) : <p>Loading...</p>}
        </ul>
        <form className={classes.Form} onSubmit={(e) => props.onMessageSentHandler(e)}>
            <input className={classes.Input} placeholder="Type your message..." onChange={(e) => props.onInputChangedHandler(e)} value={props.messageInput} />
            <button className={classes.Btn}><FontAwesomeIcon color="white" icon='paper-plane' className={classes.PaperPlaneIcon} /></button>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

And also I tried to use async:

```
{messages ? messages && messages.map(async msg => {
                const messageClass = msg.userId === props.userId ? classes.Sent : classes.Recieved;
                const messageListItem = await function() {
                    firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(msg.author).get().then(doc => {
                        return <li className={messageClass + ' ' + classes.Message} key={msg.id}>
                            <label>{msg.author !== props.userId ? doc.data().userName : 'You'}</label>
                            <p className={classes.MessageContent}>{msg.messageContent}</p>
                        </li>
                    });
                }
                return messageListItem();
            }) : <p>Loading...</p>}
```

But it throws this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
in ul (at ChatRoom.js:16)
```

Comment: Never use async functions with `then()` in the rendered part of your component. Theoretically you could do it in `useEffect()`, but you would lose benefints of firestore. In your use-case you should use the library `@react-firebase/firestore` and `<FirestoreCollection>` to do it properly. Docs: https://react-firebase-js.com/docs/react-firestore-database/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

**Hi there!** As you are using functional components, the best way to make the grade will be using the useEffect hook along with the useState hook.

### From the documentation:

What is a Hook? A Hook is a special function that lets you “hook into” React features. For example, useState is a Hook that lets you add React state to function components. And, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

### An example of that would be something like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
...
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  if(loading) return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  if(error) return <h2>Error!</h2>;
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true); 
    // your async call
    fetchData()
    .then(resData => {
      setData(resData);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      setError(true);
    });
  }, []);
 
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(item => (
        <li key={item.key}>
          <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

### For more info

useState: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
useEffect: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: But I'm already getting data from database in real time by using useCollectionData hook. What I wanted to do is to change username depending on user's user id in map function.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all the `li` items as part of an array in state called `messageList.` Then in a `useEffect()` hook, you can asynchronously get the data from firebase and update the state.

```js
const [messageList, setMessageList] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
   messages.map(msg => {
       const messageClass = msg.userId === props.userId ? classes.Sent : classes.Recieved;
       let messageAuthorName;
       firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(msg.author).get().then(doc => {
            messageAuthorName = doc.data().userName;
       }).then(() => {
             setMessageList(prev => [...prev, 
                <li className={messageClass + ' ' + classes.Message} key={msg.id}>
                  <label>{msg.author !== props.userId ? msg.author : 'You'}</label>
                  <p className={classes.MessageContent}>{msg.messageContent}</p>
                </li>])
       })
}, [])
```

Then you can return the list of messages in the `ul`:

```js
<div className={classes.ChatRoomContainer}>
        <ul>
            {messages && messages !== null ? messages &&
             messageList
             : <p>Loading...</p>}
        </ul>
        <form className={classes.Form} onSubmit={(e) => props.onMessageSentHandler(e)}>
            <input className={classes.Input} placeholder="Type your message..." onChange={(e) => props.onInputChangedHandler(e)} value={props.messageInput} />
            <button className={classes.Btn}><FontAwesomeIcon color="white" icon='paper-plane' className={classes.PaperPlaneIcon} /></button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't wok unfortunately. So it is impossible to return something only after some asynchronous function?